# How do you update an array list

Tags: java

I'm trying to add an update function to my HTML table. At the minute I have an insert and delete but I'm trying to figure out how to add an update function. I've been stuck on this for a while. I tried adding the .edit but that doesnt seem to work.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

**Here is my service class:**

```
@Service
    public class ProductService {
    
        static List<Product> productList = new ArrayList();
    
        static {
            productList.add(new Product("XG809", "Contemporary Office Desk", "Concentrating on the job is a lot easier when everyone has a place that’s comfortable to work at.", 25.00, 69.00, 18));
            productList.add(new Product("BG565", "Bed Frame With Storage", "With the comfort and quality you get from our sturdy single beds, you’ll wake up refreshed and ready to roll. ", 139.00, 175.00, 5));
            productList.add(new Product("PO262", "TV Stand", "Our TV stands and TV cabinets are there to cut the clutter and get things organised.", 69.99, 89.99, 120));
            productList.add(new Product("MC342", "Kitchen Unit", "They make the most of your wall by giving you extra storage, and the right kitchen shelf can boost the style of your decor too", 23.00, 65.99, 89));
            productList.add(new Product("WS341", "Folding Chair", "You can fold the chair, so it takes less space when you're not using it.", 12.00, 35.99, 30));
            productList.add(new Product("TF875", "Berkant Kitchen", "Express yourself in the place where all of life’s daily activities take place.in our stylish, yet personalised kitchen..", 8900.00, 12200.99, 4));
    
        }
    
        public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
            return productList;
        }// end getAllProducts
    
        public boolean addAProduct(Product p) {
            return productList.add(p);
        }
    
        public void deleteAProduct(String code) {
    
            Iterator<Product> iterator = productList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Product product = iterator.next();
                if (product.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }//end deleteAProduct
        
        public boolean editAProduct (Product p) {
            return productList.edit(p);
        }
    }
```

**Here is my JSP Page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>All Products</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <security:authorize access="hasRole('SUPERADMIN')"><p>Welcome ${uname}, <a href="/logout">Logout</a></p></security:authorize>
        <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')"><p>Welcome ${uname},<a href="/logout">Logout</a></p></security:authorize>
        <security:authorize access="hasRole('USER')"><p>Welcome ${uname},<a href="/logout">Logout</a></p></security:authorize>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Code</th>
                <th align="left">Name</th>
                <th align="left">Description</th>
                <th align="left">Buy Price</th>
                <th align="left">Sell Price</th>
                <th align="left">Qty In Stock</th>
                <th align="left">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${productList}" var="product"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>${product.code}</td>
                    <td>${product.name}</td>
                    <td>${product.description}</td>
                    <td><fmt:setLocale value="en_EUR"/>
                        <fmt:formatNumber value="${product.buyPrice}" type="currency"/></td>
                    <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${product.sellPrice}" type="currency"/></td>
                    <td>${product.quantityInStock}</td>
                    <td><security:authorize access="hasRole('SUPERADMIN')">
                            <a href="addProduct">Insert</a>
                            <a href="/admin/deleteProduct?code=${product.code}">Delete</a>
                        </security:authorize>
                        <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                            <a href="/admin/deleteProduct?code=${product.code}">Delete</a>
                        </security:authorize>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its just like you did in delete method of yours, ArrayList as a static method `set(int position, Object obj) ` this will update the object on that position.

Comment: There is no `edit` method in interface `java.util.List`. Maybe you are looking for method [set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#set(int,E))?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't reinvent the wheel here. Libraries like Primefaces have a very convenient component for this - take a look at the [Data Table](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/crud.xhtml)

Comment: @maio290 I dont need to use javascript or bootstrap plugins etc. It just has to be a basic html page

Comment: Surely, you don't need to - but I don't think spending any time on this is worth the effort unless it is for learning purposes. However, in order to create and edit an entry, you have to have inputs whose values have to be send to the server (preferably by a POST request). There's no way around that and your code is lacking that completely.

Comment: Is the question about Java or about how to do an update in JSP? The tags only mention Java.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList method [set(int index,
E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) is for updating an element of the list. You pass to it the position in the list (index) and the new value.